# How do change flutter htmlToolbarOptions background color?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHwy2.jpg)Recently I'm trying to develop a project so there I want to somehow separate htmlToolbarOptions and htmlEditorOptions. So that it looks easy to identify the separate section.